# How Do I Fix Mail Send Stopping at 500 Sends?

Tags: civimail, joomla

When using Civi Mail, we have a recurring issue wherein the system stops sending emails at 500 sends. The job shows as incomplete.

It is not a php timeout, as the hosting company (https://www.rochen.com/) has increased all our limits during testing, with no change.

We can re-initiate the mail send, and it will send out the next set of 500 emails, then stop again. We have to continue manually triggering the send to get the full job completed.

Any thoughts on the culprit?

System info:
CiviCRM 4.2.6
Joomla 2.5.28
php 5.3.29
MySQL 5.5.42-cli

Comment: Have you checked your cron setup? Without cron running you'll always be limited by whatever batch size you set.

Comment: We have. It runs as scheduled, and nothing's changed in the cron since we set up the site, yet this problem just started.

Comment: We're sending 500 per cron execution, and the cron executes every 10 minutes, which means 3,000 per hour. I don't want to risk getting blacklisted by sending out much more than that per hour.

Answer (score 11):

Check **Administer menu > CiviMail > Mailer Settings**, and see if the "Mailer Batch Limit" is set to 500.

Comment: Here is the direct link to the "Mailer Settings" page: <<yourdomain>>/civicrm/admin/mail?reset=1

Comment: The Batch Limit is indeed set to 500. Is it safe to set it to 0 (unlimited)? Our server's pretty beefy.

Comment: @JosephCotten - yeah, I always leave it at 0 unless the webhost/ESP is throttling e-mail.  I haven't seen a mailing over 38K e-mails, but I've had no problem up to that amount!  Though the default is 0, so I'd try to find out who set it to 500 and why.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like a cron/scheduled tasks issue.

CiviCRM has a scheduled tasks system to organise jobs that need running at regular intervals. This in turn requires that something pokes it into action frequently (e.g. every 15 mins). Typically on Linux this is done with the system's cron utility.

Without CiviCRM being given chance to run its scheduled tasks, it will only ever do one batch - there's nothing to give it chance to run a second batch.

Setting this up is detailed [in the book](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/) and [on the wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs).

In brief, if you're on Linux + Drupal hosting, then you want a line like this in `/etc/crontab`

```
*/15 * *   *   *   <USER>  umask 0002; /usr/bin/php /var/www/your.civi.site/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php -j -s <example.com> -u admin -p '<DATABASE PASSWORD>' -e Job -a execute
```

Nb. you might like to put those commands in another shell script and then just reference that so as to avoid your database password entering your syslog.

Comment: Generally you can use crontab to list and manage crons: `crontab -l` to list for the current user, `crontab -e` to edit crontabs for the current user

Comment: Can you explain the F in -p 'F<DATABASE PASSWORD>' ?

Comment: Yes. All passwords must begin with F. To do otherwise it's a grave security mistake. Um, no, it was a typo! I've removed it, thanks!