# Is this scheduled cronjob setup correctly?

Tags: civimail, cron-job

I set up this cronjob. Does this cover whatever I set in the GUI Scheduled Jobs? Or, do I need to set up a cronjob for each? If for each, what is the purpose of this GUI?

As per [Scheduled Jobs:](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-PHPclimethod)

> CIVI_ROOT="~/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm"
>
> PHP=nice -n19 /usr/bin/php
>
> PARAMS= -j -s[domain] -u[user] -p[password] -a execute
>
> */1 * * * * cd $CIVI_ROOT; $PHP bin/cli.php $PARAMS

Answer (score 2):

Yes, executing the standard cron job, which is the cron.php file as you have it, executes any and all jobs which are enabled on the  **CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Scheduled Jobs**  page.

Comment: Do I need to have "-e Job" argument in there, too?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that this is not working. It will not fire the cron unless I put the user and password inline. Using the tokens is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check the answer here which is a bit detailed:

[How Do I Fix Mail Send Stopping at 500 Sends?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2/mail-send-stopping-at-500-sends?rq=1)

Comment: It appears to be the same as what I posted, eh?

Comment: I don't see why it's the same question--that other question is regarding the email job only--your question is about how to execute all the jobs.

Comment: I think he was referring me to a long standing question I've had about that. No worries.